# AWS SCT default binding is not set for column

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, binding, aws-dms, aws-sct

I'm using AWS SCT to create the schema on my target RDS. Both source and destination engines are MS-SQL. I'm able to convert and create appropriate schema on target RDS using SCT but the **Default Binding** is not set for columns in target RDS.

[image]

The value of **Default Binding** should be **false** for this particular column as it is set to **false** in source DB.

Below is screenshot of Source DB and same column properties:
[image]

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: `'False'` isn't a valid value for a `bit`. For the column you have, it can only have a value of `0` or `1`. I *assume* by `'False'` you therefore mean `0`. If you have set the default value, have you tried setting it? `ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT df_delete_flag DEFAULT 0 FOR delete_flag;` [Use Transact-SQL to specify a default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure)

Comment: @Larnu it is set to 'false' in source and I want AWS SCT to set it to 'false' in target DB.